# WebSphere javax.naming.NamingException and connection refused

Tags: java, ejb, websphere-8

I have deployed a secure ejb on machine1, when I run the client code on the same machine, it works fine. But when I run the client code on any other machine it throws an error. which is pasted below.

**In the error it can be seen that its not taking the ip: that is provided but instead it looks in the client machine itself. Where is the problem is it in the client code or am I missing some settings in WebSphere.**

```
package org.was.tutorial.security.client;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;

import org.was.tutorial.security.bean.Calculator;

public class Client
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
   {
      //Establish the proxy with an incorrect security identity
      Properties env = new Properties();

      //username and password
      //String username="teacher1";
      //String password="teacher";


      String username="student1";
      String password="student";

      //setting up environment properties..
      env.setProperty(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username);
      env.setProperty(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
      env.setProperty(javax.naming.Context.PROVIDER_URL, "iiop://10.94.13.18:2809");
      env.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
      InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(env);
      //javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(ctx.lookup("CalculatorBean/remote"), Calculator.class);

      Calculator calculator =null;
      try{
      calculator = (Calculator)javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(ctx.lookup("CalculatorBean/remote"), Calculator.class);
      if(calculator==null){
          System.out.println("This is not going anywhere");
      }else
          System.out.println("Good. we made a progress.");

      }catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

      System.out.println("User "+username);
      System.out.println("Addition can be performed by  all");

      try
      {
         System.out.println("1 + 1 = " + calculator.add(1, 1));
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         System.out.println("Saw expected SecurityException: " + ex.getMessage());
      }

      System.out.println("Subtraction- can be performed by students only.");
      try
      {
         System.out.println("16- 4 ="+calculator.subtract(16, 4));
      }catch (Exception  ex)
      {
         System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
      }

      System.out.println("Division- can be performed by teachers only.");      
      try
      {
         System.out.println("16/4 ="+calculator.divide(16, 4));
      }catch (Exception  ex)
      {
         System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
      }
     ///cool


   }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "P=13152:O=0:CT" javax.naming.NamingException: Error getting WsnNameService properties [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: IBM  minor code: E07  completed: No]
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.mergeWsnNSProperties(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1552)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootContextFromServer(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1042)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootJndiContext(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:962)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getInitialContextInternal(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:614)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContext(WsnInitCtx.java:128)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContextIfNull(WsnInitCtx.java:765)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:164)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:179)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:423)
at com.temenos.services.ofsconnector.ejb.IntegrationFrameworkServiceClient.main(IntegrationFrameworkServiceClient.java:50)
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: IBM  minor code: E07  completed: No
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1109)
at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1463)
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1001)
at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1429)
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1618)
at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1385)
at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._request(ObjectImpl.java:458)
at com.ibm.WsnBootstrap._WsnNameServiceStub.getProperties(_WsnNameServiceStub.java:38)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.mergeWsnNSProperties(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1549)
... 9 more
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: CONNECT_FAILURE_ON_SSL_CLIENT_SOCKET - JSSL0130E: java.io.IOException: Signals that an I/O exception of some sort has occurred.  Reason:  Connection refused: connect Remote Host: 127.0.0.1  Remote Port: 9403  vmcid: 0x49421000  minor code: 80  completed: No
at com.ibm.ws.security.orbssl.WSSSLClientSocketFactoryImpl.tryToCreateConnectedSSLSocket(WSSSLClientSocketFactoryImpl.java:357)
at com.ibm.ws.security.orbssl.WSSSLClientSocketFactoryImpl.createSSLSocket(WSSSLClientSocketFactoryImpl.java:219)
at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSSSLTransportConnection.createSocket(WSSSLTransportConnection.java:236)
at com.ibm.CORBA.transport.TransportConnectionBase.connect(TransportConnectionBase.java:348)
at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport$1.run(WSTransport.java:503)
at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.getConnection(WSTransport.java:500)
at com.ibm.CORBA.transport.TransportBase.getConnection(TransportBase.java:181)
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.TransportManager.get(TransportManager.java:97)
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.GIOPImpl.getConnection(GIOPImpl.java:134)
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.GIOPImpl.locate(GIOPImpl.java:230)
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.locate(ClientDelegate.java:1696)
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate._createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1721)
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1023)
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1105)
... 17 more
```

**Update**

[image: Port Details]

I have created the node and profile using the following script:

File1:setUpEnv.bat

```
set WAS_HOME=C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer
set HOST_NAME=localhost
set PROFILE_NAME=AppSrv01

set NODE_NAME=%PROFILE_NAME%Node01
set CELL_NAME=%NODE_NAME%Cell  
set SERVER_NAME=server1

set DMGR_USER=user1
set DMGR_PASSWORD=123456
set DMGR_HOST=localhost
set DMGR_PORT=8879
```

File2:

```
CALL ./setUpEnv.bat
set WAS_HOME=C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer
CALL %WAS_HOME%\bin\manageprofiles.bat -create -profileName %PROFILE_NAME% -       profilePath %WAS_HOME%\profiles\%PROFILE_NAME% -templatePath %WAS_HOME%\profileTemplates\default -serverName %SERVER_NAME% -cellName %CELL_NAME% -nodeName %NODE_NAME% -hostName %HOST_NAME% -enableAdminSecurity true -adminUserName %DMGR_USER% -adminPassword %DMGR_PASSWORD%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 9403 is correct port for RMI/IIOP SSL communication (CSIV2_ SSL_ SERVERAUTH_ LISTENER_ ADDRESS). It might happen that you incorrectly installed WAS using localhost, and it sends to the client redirection for the localhost instead for its host name.

Double check WAS configuration for example via web console, in the Server -> Administration -> ports section.

If you installed WAS using localhost, you will either have to change host, or recreate provile (the second might be easier if you are a new to WAS).

Comment: Please see, the updated, also I have a question for you.So, to fix this, I need to change the profie name and host name, I want my code to take ip's rather than some characters.. so how do I make it. So my actual EJB, will be referred from many machines.

Comment: The other question that i have for you is.. If I change the host name.. How is the client knowing. which machine should it look for?

Comment: @user2900314 I don't fully understand what are your questions. Just when you will create profile, use your server machine real hostname NOT the localhost. Everything should work then. You will either have to put that hostname into the DNS or create /etc/hosts files with mapping on your clients. Of course you can also use IP directly instead of hostname while creating profile, but thats usually not recommended, as IP may change.